# Apple watch real response data

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-watch

Can you print and show me the output of this with real device I need to know the format of it.

```
- (void)didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)remoteNotification withCompletion:(void (^)(WKUserNotificationInterfaceType))completionHandler
{    
   // This method is called when a remote notification needs to be presented.
   // Implement it if you use a dynamic notification interface.
   // Populate your dynamic notification interface as quickly as possible.
   // After populating your dynamic notification interface call the completion block.
    NSLog(@"%@",remoteNotification);
    completionHandler(WKUserNotificationInterfaceTypeCustom);
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about programming, instead it is a request for someone to compile code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the Payload response for the question

```
{
"aps": {
    "alert": {
        "body": "Test message",
        "title": "Optional title"
    },
    "category": "myCategory"
},

"WatchKit Simulator Actions": [
    {
        "title": "First Button",
        "identifier": "firstButtonAction"
    }
],

"customKey": "Use this file to define a testing payload for your notifications. The aps dictionary specifies the category, alert text and title. The WatchKit Simulator Actions array can provide info for one or more action buttons in addition to the standard Dismiss button. Any other top level keys are custom payload. If you have multiple such JSON files in your project, you'll be able to select them when choosing to debug the notification interface of your Watch App."
```

}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20070515/how-do-i-access-json-data-in-an-nsmutablearray